# Wait for cftool to close, then continue execution

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'd like to call the cftool from a function/script, do my fitting, store the variables to the workspace and then resume execution of my function. Naively, one could assume that assigning a handle to the GUI and then using waitfor(), like for a graphics object, would do the job, but that was a bit short-sighted. 
Minimally this reads

```
h = cftool;
waitfor(h);
disp('happy fitting');
```

and of course does not work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cftool` does not return a handle, so you need to search for it using `findall`:

```
cftool
f = findall(0,'Type','Figure');
waitfor(f(1))
disp('Happy fitting!')
```

If you have multiple figures `f` may have multiple values and it could cause some issues. So keep track of your figures and check which position has the gui handle, before you call `waitfor`.